# Logic app skips send email action inside for each

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

My logic app has an HTTP trigger. Whenever I run the logic app manually or just copy and paste the URL on the browser it works as expected. However, when I use my QueueTriggered azure function to make a call to the logic app URL, the logic app just skips the send email action.

[Loggic app design (shows skipped actions)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucNbx.png)

[Action inside ForEach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdKr1.png)

Here is the code I have for my function app:

```
public static async Task Run([QueueTrigger("messages", Connection = "ConnectionString")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            var httpClient = HttpClientFactory.Create();
            var url = "logicAppUri";

            await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

        }
```

The content of the message is just a plain string like "test" for example.

I also tried changing the function app trigger to "When there are messages in the queue" but that also did not work.

["When there are messages in the queue" trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDSpY.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XSDP.png)

I got the same error message from Azure in both cases.

```
{"code":"ActionConditionFailed","message":"The execution of template action 'Send_email_(V2)' is skipped: there are no items to repeat."}
```

Which it doesn't make sense since there were messages in the queue.

Any idea why that's happening?

Comment: I think I need more detail in your flow to know how data going through

Comment: Don't use `async void` use `async Task`. Consider adding some logging perhaps an error is being thrown

Comment: I suspect it is some how to do with the messages that you are retrieve  from the queues just before the for each loop. Could you please provide more details there? Looks like there are no messages read?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've added more information about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to some test, this issue is caused by using queue triggered function. The queue triggered function will triggered when there are new messages in queue and read the messages. So when the `httpClient` call the logic app uri in funciton, there are no messages in the queue. The "Get messages" action will get a 0 size list, so the "For each" will execute 0 time.

For your requirement, you can just use "[When there are messages in a queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azurequeues/#when-there-are-messages-in-a-queue)" in logic app. Please refer to my logic app below:

[image]

As the trigger will triggered by every message, so we do not need to use "For each" to loop the messages.

Hope it helps~

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time, but that also did not work. I still got the same problem, it just skips the actions inside the for each.

Comment: Hi @YgorD. I think if we use "When there are messages in queue" trigger in logic app, we do not need to use "For each"(as I mentioned at the bottom of my answer). Just use a trigger(when there are messages in a queue) and an action(send email) as the screenshot I provided, that's enough(except you may need to add an action to delete the message). The trigger will be triggered by every message, so we do not need to use "For each" in logic app.